# Convert date to timestamp using lambda function while reading the file

Tags: python, csv, pandas, lambda, timestamp

I am reading csv file which contains date in this format:

```
date
01/05/2014
01/05/2014
01/05/2014
01/05/2014
01/05/2014
01/05/2014
01/05/2014
01/05/2014
01/05/2014
```

I can not use date like this in string format, which I need to convert into numeric timestamp.

So I wrote this code:

```
Train = pd.read_csv("train.tsv", sep='\t') 
Train['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(Train['date']).apply(lambda a: a.timestamp())
```

This give me:

> Train['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(Train['date']).apply(lambda a: a.timestamp())
>   AttributeError: 'Timestamp' object has no attribute 'timestamp'

Could you please correct me to get in timestamp in lambda?

Edit code :

```
Train = pd.read_csv("data_scientist_assignment.tsv", sep='\t', parse_dates=['date'])
#print df.head()
# Train['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(Train['date']).apply(lambda a: a.timestamp())
Train['timestamp'] = Train.date.values.astype(np.int64)
x1=["timestamp", "hr_of_day"]
test=pd.read_csv("test.csv")
print(Train.columns)
print(test.columns)
model = LogisticRegression()
model.fit(Train[x1], Train["vals"])
print(model)
print model.score(Train[x1], Train["vals"])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need add parameter `parse_dates` to [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) with column name converted to `datetime`:

```
import pandas as pd
import io

temp=u"""date
01/05/2014
01/05/2014
01/05/2014
01/05/2014
01/05/2014
01/05/2014
01/05/2014
01/05/2014
01/05/2014"""
#after testing replace io.StringIO(temp) to filename
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(temp), sep='\t', parse_dates=['date'])

print (df)
        date
0 2014-01-05
1 2014-01-05
2 2014-01-05
3 2014-01-05
4 2014-01-05
5 2014-01-05
6 2014-01-05
7 2014-01-05
8 2014-01-05

print (df.dtypes)
date    datetime64[ns]
dtype: object
```

Another solution is add numbers for order of column `date` - in sample it is first column, so add `0` (python counts from `0`):

```
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(temp), sep='\t', parse_dates=[0])

print (df)
        date
0 2014-01-05
1 2014-01-05
2 2014-01-05
3 2014-01-05
4 2014-01-05
5 2014-01-05
6 2014-01-05
7 2014-01-05
8 2014-01-05

print (df.dtypes)
date    datetime64[ns]
dtype: object
```

---

Then need convert column to `numpy array` by [`values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.values.html) and cast to `int`:

```
#unix time in ns
df.date = df.date.values.astype(np.int64)
print (df)
                  date
0  1388880000000000000
1  1388880000000000000
2  1388880000000000000
3  1388880000000000000
4  1388880000000000000
5  1388880000000000000
6  1388880000000000000
7  1388880000000000000
8  1388880000000000000

#unix time in us
df.date = df.date.values.astype(np.int64) // 1000
print (df)
               date
0  1388880000000000
1  1388880000000000
2  1388880000000000
3  1388880000000000
4  1388880000000000
5  1388880000000000
6  1388880000000000
7  1388880000000000
8  1388880000000000
```

```
#unix time in ms
df.date = df.date.values.astype(np.int64) // 1000000
#df.date = pd.to_datetime(df.date, unit='ms')
print (df)
            date
0  1388880000000
1  1388880000000
2  1388880000000
3  1388880000000
4  1388880000000
5  1388880000000
6  1388880000000
7  1388880000000
8  1388880000000

#unix time in s
df.date = df.date.values.astype(np.int64) // 1000000000
print (df)
         date
0  1388880000
1  1388880000
2  1388880000
3  1388880000
4  1388880000
5  1388880000
6  1388880000
7  1388880000
8  1388880000
```

Comment: Thanks, but still my next operation fails saying `'Timestamp' object has no attribute 'timestamp'`

Comment: Yes, I add solution, plese check it.

Answer (score 1):

Another short way to go about this is to use [to_datetime()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html):

```
In [209]: df['date']
Out[209]: 
0    01/05/2014
1    01/05/2014
2    01/05/2014
3    01/05/2014
4    01/05/2014
5    01/05/2014
6    01/05/2014
7    01/05/2014
8    01/05/2014
Name: date, dtype: object

In [210]: df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])

In [211]: df['date']
Out[211]: 
0   2014-01-05
1   2014-01-05
2   2014-01-05
3   2014-01-05
4   2014-01-05
5   2014-01-05
6   2014-01-05
7   2014-01-05
8   2014-01-05
Name: date, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Also, you can get seconds like this:

```
In [232]: df['date'].astype(pd.np.int64) // 10**9
Out[232]: 
0    1388880000
1    1388880000
2    1388880000
3    1388880000
4    1388880000
5    1388880000
6    1388880000
7    1388880000
8    1388880000
Name: date, dtype: int64
```